# Django Media Files Not Uploading to S3 Amazon from main site

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, django-storage

I'm stuck and confused trying to get this work.

I'm running Django on Heroku, using Python 2.7.14 using Django-Storages 1.6.5 trying to upload to Amazon S3.  Deploying my site, I can use the Admin site in Django and upload a file to S3 with no problem.  Using the non-admin site, I try to upload a media file and it doens't work.  The file upload field is is denied by Amazon.  Static works with no issue.

Why would the Admin site be able to upload media files and the main site not be able to, when they use the same models?

Comment: Share your code please. what it looks like in template.html, forms.py, models.py.... the more the better.....

Comment: There was an error in t he code where the views were incorrect.